# Will Google app Script triggers send mails if I set out of office in my google calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have a script in my Google app Script that send some mails on timely triggers.
But today I set a event Out-Of-Office in my google calendar.
and the trigger do not send any mail.
Can you help me here what's going on?
It was working fine since 2 months it's sending mails even on Sundays.

Script I am using.

```
function send_mails() {
    MailApp.sendEmail("my_mail_id", "subject", "body of mail")
}
```

It send me mail first time ( When I didn't add any Out-Of-Office)
but not after I add OOF.

[image: Trigers]
[image: Mails]

Comment: I am think that might be I am busy so it won't send any mail from my username.

Comment: I don't think there's any correlation betwen setting out of office and your time based triggers.  There may be something wrong with your code but I can't really know without looking at it.

Comment: How much have you investigated this for yourself? Do your triggers start working when you remove the out-of-office event? And do they stop working when you re-set it? And so on...? What is the empirical (i.e. observed) evidence for a connection between these two things?

Comment: Check your executions and see if you can find any problems there.

Comment: Yes I will update my findins soon.

Comment: Done with updates.

Comment: I can't proof that there is some connection that is why I am asking.

Comment: You have to open them to see if there are any errors and if there's no errors try adding Logger.log() to see if  things are working as expected.

Comment: "_I can't prove that there is some connection_" - OK, but you can show strong evidence that there is almost certainly _no_ connection, if you remove your out-of-office and e-mails are still not being sent.

Comment: Isn't there any failed status in your execution tab during your OOO period?

Comment: Nope there are no Fail status.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending one email every minute with MailApp then chances are you have already exceeded your daily quota.  Try adding `Logger.log(MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota())` If it's zero then that's it no more for today.

Comment: Okay I will check this Thanks